# how to get geocode in R?

Tags: r, geocoding, r-maptools

i have tried 2 approaches to get the long lat of location.

```
install.packages("maptools")
library(maptools)
A1 <- data.frame(A1= c("Dordrecht", "Berlin", "New York", 
                                    "Batu Pahat", "Edinburgh"), 
                                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

result <- lapply(A1[, 1], geocode_OSM)
```

or

```
A2_df <- mutate_geocode(A1, loc)
```

but both do not work

```
        loc
  1    Dordrecht
  2    Berlin
  3    New York
  4    Batu Pahat 
  5    Edinburgh
```

any ideas to get the respectively  code without API key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```r
library(tmaptools)

geocode_OSM(A1$A1)

#>        query       lat        lon   lat_min   lat_max    lon_min    lon_max
#> 1  Dordrecht 51.795881   4.677935 51.714123 51.823358   4.620404   4.884643
#> 2     Berlin 52.517037  13.388860 52.357036 52.677036  13.228860  13.548860
#> 3   New York 40.712728 -74.006015 40.477399 40.916179 -74.259090 -73.700181
#> 4 Batu Pahat  1.933333 103.000000  1.616728  2.200501 102.774169 103.256164
#> 5  Edinburgh 55.953346  -3.188375 55.818792 56.004084  -3.449533  -3.074951
```

**data**

```
A1 <- data.frame(A1= c("Dordrecht", "Berlin", "New York", 
                       "Batu Pahat", "Edinburgh"), 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>